# Azure Authorization Exception when retrieve access token using HTTP native client application via HTTP Client in .Net Core

Tags: api, azure, .net-core, access-token

I am trying to deploy azure vm using REST API/ Fluent API in .net core application. when retrieve the access token using with help of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory dll does not support the UserCredential class so that i have used the below http client method to retrieve access token. But the below code returns the unauthorized token for invoking rest api. Any help would be appreciated.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                string tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token";
                var body = "resource=https://management.azure.com&client_id=xxxxxxxx&grant_type=password&username=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxxx";
                var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                var result = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, stringContent).ContinueWith<string>((response) =>
                {
                    return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have turn on Azure Multi-Factor Authentication for the user, **it will  not work**.

If you registry the web app/API application,lease have a try to use an AAD native app then it should work. More details you could refer to this [document -Constraints & Limitations section](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/).

> No web sites/confidential clients
>
> This is not an ADAL limitation, but an AAD setting. You can only use those flows from a native client. A confidential client, such as a web site, **cannot use direct user credentials**.

**Note :** You also could use the fiddler to catch the detail unauthorized  error info.

If azure SDK is possible, you also could use the Azure flunent SDK to do that.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;

var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromUser("username","password",clientId, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithDefaultSubscription();

var disk = azure.Disks.Define(diskname)
            .WithRegion(localtion)
            .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourcgroup)
            .WithWindowsFromVhd("vhrul")
            .Create();

var vm = azure.VirtualMachines.Define(vmname)

            .WithRegion("localtion")  //eastasia

            .WithNewResourceGroup(resourcgroup)

            .WithNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
            
            .WithPrimaryPrivateIPAddressDynamic()

            .WithoutPrimaryPublicIPAddress()

            .WithSpecializedOSDisk(disk, OperatingSystemTypes.Windows)

            .WithSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardA0)

            .Create();
```